# Can a DB table with just one column be in 3NF and can a table with two fields both the primary key be in 3NF

Tags: database-design, normalization

Hi this maybe simple but I'm trying to teach myself database design and I was wondering if the following is true.

1. Is a table with just one column in 3NF given that each value is a primary key?
   e.g.
      Supplier table with the column name, assuming each supplier name is always unique
2. Is a table with two fields that make a composite primary key in 3NF?
   e.g. 
      orderitems table with the columns ordernumber and itemID, assuming that order number and item ID are held in their own relevant tables e.g. order and stock_items.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any relation which has only one candidate key and has no non-key attributes is automatically in at least 6th Normal Form.